# MongoDB - query on all sharded collections without shardkey

Tags: mongodb, sharding, mongodb-query

I have several shard-(ed) collections. The collection is user requests. and the shard key is User Id.

I have a field named "Execution Time" and I want query all the requests in a period of time (lte and gte).

The index is with the shard key, but my query is without. I would like not to put all the shard Key in query with a "in" operator because I have a 1000 shard keys (users).. futher more to do that i need to get all user ids on every query - it means 2 queries each time instead of 1.

But still i want to use an index.. one option is to add userId > 0 < maxUserId to the query, but its look wrong, any ideas?

What is the right approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand it will use an index it will instead do a scatter and gather operation

Comment: but there is more info